# Trying to create a stored procedure for shopping basket in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that adds to shopping basket in SQL Server. This procedure should take the person number, product number and order number as input and put that product in to order. It should also be able to send NULL in the order number then, a new order is should be created.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    PersonID CHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Firstname varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Zip INT NOT NULL,
    City varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Telephone CHAR (10)
    Email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Customerorder
(
    Order number CHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Time TIME NOT NULL,
    Total INT,
    PersonID CHAR (10)

    FK_Customerorder_Customer 
       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) 
            REFERENCES Customer(PersonID)
);

CREATE TABLE ProductOrders
(
    Ordernumber CHAR (10),
    ProductID CHAR (10)
    Number INT NOT NULL,

    PK_Productorder 
       CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ordernumber, productID);
    FK_Productorder_Customerorder 
       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Ordernumber) 
           REFERENCES Customer order (ordernumber) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FK_Productorder_Product 
       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (productID) 
           REFERENCES Product (productID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductID CHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount INT NOT NULL,
    ModelID CHAR (10)
    CategoryID CHAR (10)

    CONSTRAINT 
        FK_Product_Model FOREIGN KEY (ModelID) 
           REFERENCES (ModelID)
    FK_Product_Category 
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) 
        REFERENCES Category (CategoryID)
);
```

This is my procedure, that won't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDToBasket
    (@Ordernumber char(10), 
     @ProductID CHAR(10),
     @PersonID char(10) 
    )
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT @Ordernumber 
               FROM Customerorder  
               WHERE Ordernumber = @Ordernumber 
                 AND PersonID = @PersonID)
        UPDATE Productorder
        SET Amount = Amount + 1
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID 
          AND Ordernumber = @Ordernumber 
          AND PersonID = @PersonID
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Productorder (Ordernumber, ProductID, Amount) 
        VALUES (@Ordernumber, @PersonID, 
                (SELECT ProductID 
                 FROM Product 
                 WHERE @ProductID = @ProductID));  
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no benefit to first see if a row exists and then update it. Just update it and then check to see if a row was updated. You also have your columns all mixed up and you left PersonID out of your insert.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDToBasket
( 
    @Ordernumber char(10), 
    @ProductID CHAR(10)
    --, @PersonID char(10) don't think this is needed
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Productorder
    SET Amount = Amount + 1
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID 
        AND Ordernumber = @Ordernumber 
        AND PersonID = @PersonID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO Productorder 
        (
            Ordernumber
            , ProductID
            , Amount
        ) 
        VALUES
        (
            @Ordernumber
            , @ProductID
            , 1
        )
END
```

This type of thing is commonly referred to as an upsert. In other words it updates and inserts in a single procedure. You can also the MERGE statement to accomplish this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i still have a problem. PersonID column does not exist in Productorder. I have my PersonID in my Customer table. How can I join these two? I need this procedure to take PersonID as input.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. You are correct though that PersonID is not in that table. It was part of your original insert so I just assumed it needed to be there. If you have the OrderNumber then you really don't need to worry about the PersonID. If you insert into the ProductOrder table and that belongs to a specific PersonID I don't think you need to worry about it. Simply remove it from the above. OrderNumber is unique so you can't have more than 1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check your begin/end statement again. You don't need it and if you use it then make sure it is valid.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDToBasket
( 
    @Ordernumber char(10), 
    @ProductID CHAR(10),
    @PersonID char(10) 
)
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT @Ordernumber FROM Customerorder WHERE Ordernumber = @Ordernumber AND PersonID = @PersonID)
       UPDATE Productorder
       SET Amount = Amount + 1
       WHERE ProductID = @ProductID AND Ordernumber = @Ordernumber AND PersonID = @PersonID
   ELSE
        INSERT INTO Productorder (Ordernumber, ProductID, Amount) 
        VALUES(@Ordernumber,@ProductID ,1)
END
```

Comment: I don't think they want the ProductID to be the Amount which is what this code is doing. Well actually this won't work at all because your subquery in the insert will get every row in the Product table because your where predicate is wrong.

Comment: I would always put a BEGIN after the "AS" and an END at the end.